# Creating regions (set of lat, lng) on map using other than ArcMap?

Tags: polygon, coordinate-system, polygon-creation

I'm writing a project for school and as a part of the project I need to tell if a certain point is within a given region (which is a polygon made of lat, lng tuples).

So far I was working with http://www.doogal.co.uk/polylines.php but unfortunately this isn't enough when I want to draw 50 areas, name them and keep them organized.

What's the easiest way to achieve what I need? I tried using ArcGIS's ArcMap but that seemed like a total overkill, it would take me too much time to learn how to work with this program and I don't need 99% of the features it provides.

Comment: What language are you writing this in? OGR should be able to do it... create a polygon geometry for each grid and then use the contains() method http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a7fa96d0f125c10b0c2dedfb69d815cb6 for each point... OGR is the little brother of GDAL and is open source; ready to use for python (reccomended), C#, C++, ruby, Java... and many more on Windows, Mac and Linux so it's most likely to be available for your environment and also most likely to be usable again in the future.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I'm looking for that tool to easily create these polygon geometry, everything else is ready for work. I'm not a GIS person, I guess I'll never be. I just need to complete this simple task :(